# How to justify text after adding ellipsis

Tags: css, ellipsis, justify

I have one container which is of width 150px; here I am displaying 'username', 'location', 'mobile number', 'email', each one is displayed in a separate line. I'm using the ellipsis for longer texts. the problems after adding ellipsis mentioned below

1. for numbers there is a space in between ellipsis and last character
2. The contents inside the container is not center justified after the ellipses are added.

[Here is the CodePen link for recreating this issue.](https://codepen.io/rk150390/pen/pZMvLw)

```
.target {
    width: 150px;
    background-color:#dc143c;
    color: #fff;
}

.target-title div {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Use "text-align: justify " style for target-title and the ellipses behaviour might be because the text is too long without spaces. try giving the valid texts with spaces

Comment: what do you mean by "centred justified after the ellipses" ?